# How can I prevent two types of SpriteKit nodes from colliding with each other?

Tags: ios, ios7, collision, sprite-kit

I'm writing a small game using Apple Sprite Kit.

I'm having trouble with the collisions.
Sometimes I dont want two skSpriteNodes with physicsBodys to interact.

as an example I have the HERO , ENEMYS and SHOTS and I want the SHOTS only to interact with the ENEMYS.

But when 2 shots collide together then they change their position.!

the code for the shot is

```
   shot.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:shot.size];
   shot.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
   shot.physicsBody.allowsRotation = FALSE;
   shot.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = playerShotCategory;
   shot.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = enemyCategory;
```

and the code for the enemy is

```
   activeGameObject.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:activeGameObject.size];
    activeGameObject.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    activeGameObject.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = enemyCategory;
    activeGameObject.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = playerCategory | playerShotCategory;
    activeGameObject.physicsBody.allowsRotation = FALSE;
```

Comment: What are `playerShotCategory`, `enemyCategory` and `playerCategory`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only want shots to interact with enemies, you'll need to add this code:

```
shot.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = enemyCategory;
activeGameObject.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = playerShotCategory|playerCategory;
```

See the [documentation for collisionBitMask](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/collisionBitMask) for more information. You may need to tinker with the collisionBitMask if you have other categories that you want involved in the collisions.

Comment: Thanks it worked Great. I did not understand the meaning of the .collisionbitmask